# search button link url manager in yii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

i have implementing URL management in

```
Unable to resolve the request "'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php/recipe/course".
```

i added search function code. please tell whats needs to change:

```
<form class="navbar-form " role="search" name="searchform" method="post" action="'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php/recipe/course"  id="menu-form-style" onsubmit="return ValidateSearchForm();">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="course" id="course" placeholder="Quick Search...." class="form-control" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();">
```

Comment: try `action="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php/recipe/course';?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this **NOT TESTED**

```
$action = Yii::app()->createUrl('/recipe/course')

echo '<form class="navbar-form " role="search" 
            name="searchform" method="post" 
            action="'.$action.'"  id="menu-form-style" 
            onsubmit="return ValidateSearchForm();">';
```

Comment: i added your code. but this error showing. Unable to resolve the request "'.$action.'".

Comment: action="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php/recipe/course';?>" this code is working fine. thanks for you posting